# How to create Firebase Blob from Dart List

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a very large List defined in Dart - 100,000 integers. I want to now create a Firebase document that will contain the List as a Blob.  I do not want any of the list entries to be indexed by Firebase or for Firebase to do any analysis of the list. As far as I know I will need to define this as an array on my Firebase console. Will this lead to analysis of the list by Firebase?  How do I create the document in Dart to ensure that the blob is not analyzed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore automatically creates an index for every field in your documents. You can exempt a field from being auto-indexed in your rules, either in the [indexes panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/indexes/single-field/manage) in the Firebase console, or in your your rules file.

For example, here are the exemptions I have on one of my projects, where I have very large `hash` and `count` map fields in my `geoindexes` collection:
[image]